# AWS Cognito - getSessionInBackground fails when ID token needs refreshing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My ID token is valid for an hour. When I call getSessionInBackground on the CognitoUser object in my service call after an hour, my call fails. Isn't this supposed to return a new ID token if the previous one has expired? Doesn't help that this behavior is not consistently reproducible - it only happens on some screens. Also, it only seems to be happening in Android, not iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen cuz in the sdk is not completely thread safe, this bug happens in aws-sdk-version <2.3, cuz one thread reads the correct value and if the token is expired, it clears the cachedToken which leaves nothing for the second thread to read, and the second thread assumes that no tokens exist(while the first thread is refreshing the token) and hence throws a user not authorized exception.

If you are using aws-sdk2.2 this is prominent bug, and you can use the following code snippet to fix it:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            CognitoUser user = userPool.getCurrentUser();

            user.getSessionInBackground(new AuthenticationHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final CognitoUserSession userSession) {
                    Log.d("Authenticator.java", userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken().toString());
                    semaphore.release();
                    callback.onSuccess(userSession);
                }

                @Override
                public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String UserId) {

                    semaphore.release();
                    callback.onNeedsPassword();
                }

                @Override
                public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {

                    semaphore.release();
                    callback.onNeedsPassword();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(final Exception exception) {

                    semaphore.release();
                    callback.onFailure(exception);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

There is also a bug in the current aws-sdk-2.4 version, related to this which increases your network traffic if you make multiple calls to aws to get a new ID token.(its an edge case, but still)
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/pull/272